# Set network proxy by group on Open Directory

Tags: macos, osx-server

I have an OS X Server with Open Directory. I am wondering if there is a way a group can be set to use a proxy when a user from that group logs in, and to remove the proxy if a user from a different group logs in.

Edit:
What I need to do is if User A (in Group A) logs in, an HTTP and HTTPS proxy is configured. But if User B (in Group B) logs in, the HTTP and HTTPS proxy is removed. I was able to set it up as explained below, however, I can only change the proxy settings for Wi-Fi adapters, the Ethernet adapter does not have proxy settings. The global HTTP proxy option only proxies HTTP but not HTTPS protocols allowing users to view blacklisted sites on HTTPS.

Is there any way to apply proxy settings on Ethernet, or any other way to apply HTTP and HTTPS proxy settings?

Comment: There may be a way. Could you tell us exactly what you are trying to do at the top level rather than the bottom problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You will have to use `Profile Manager` and manage the settings on the Mac. Set up a default profile with the default proxy settings for the managed Mac.

You can then set the profile for any of the groups you create in `Open Directory` to override those settings.

A `Profile Manager` tutorial is a little beyond an answer here but check out:

http://www.apple.com/au/support/lionserver/profilemanager/

and

http://krypted.com/mac-security/configuring-using-profile-manager-2-in-os-x-mountain-lion-server/

For the Ethernet proxy settings you will have to use a `Custom Settings` payload. The Ethernet proxy settings are in `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist` so you will have to import them once with no proxies set then set the proxies and import them into the second profile.

You will find `Custom Settings` at the bottom of the settings list on the left of the Profile Manager screen.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! However, is there a way to set HTTP and HTTPS proxies? I updated my question to have a bit more info.

Comment: Updated my answer to cover proxies under Ethernet.

Comment: thank you for that update, I see how it works now. One more side question, does this need to be by device? Since it references the ethernet interface by uuid, will it affect every mac or just that interface?

Comment: What you do is delete the parts of the prefs that specify the exact Mac so that only the part you want to set gets pushed. If you have a good read of Charles Edge's tutorial at krypted.com he has some more details on that.

Comment: can any email me this file please? I can't get this to work myself (helpdesk @ theockendonacademy.com)